# gpt4all v.2.4.19 - model downloaded but is not installing (on MacOS Ventura 13.3.1)

Tags: gpt4all

gpt4all UI has successfully downloaded three model but the Install button doesn't show up for any of them. Instead of that, after the model is downloaded and MD5 is checked, the download button appears again. And in the main window the same message "You need to download models" appears.

I also tried to add my ChatGPT4 API key and click on Install - also here nothing happens.

I expected that after one of the models is downloaded, a button "Install" will appear or the model will be installed automatically as it is suggested in the description on https://gpt4all.io/index.html.

Am I missing something in the configuration? Or should I explicitly do something to install the models?

Thanks

[Download model dialog and downloaded models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph0D3.png)
[Settings dialog shows that there is no model installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9sNG.png)
[Main dialog still shows the message to download a model despite having three of them in the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5D4FI.png)

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you gotten it to work yet? I'm on macOS, is that true for you too?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it - you need to install the latest Python version from https://www.python.org/, and then all the functionality of gpt4all starts to work.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here. Just closed the application (once the models are downloaded) and restarted.